# Работа с одномерным динамическим массивом

Tags: массивы, c, указатели, c++

Добрый день всем! Писал лабораторную работу с использованием операторов new и delete для работы с одномерным массивом динамически. И возникла проблема: при выполнении программы мне выдается непонятно число.
Вот само задание:

*"Посчитать сумму модулей элементов массива, которые расположены после первого нулевого элемента."*

Вот мой код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <time.h>
#include <cmath>
#include <algorithm>
#include <conio.h>
#include <locale.h>

using namespace std;

void add_mas_values(int *A, int n);
int mod_sum(int *A, int n);


int main()  {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "RUS");
    int n;
    cout << "Задайте размер массива" << endl;
    cin >> n;
    int *mas = new int[n];
    add_mas_values(mas, n);
    cout << "Сумма модулей элементов массива, что расположенны после первого нулевого элемента: ";
    cout << mod_sum(mas, n);
    cout << endl;

    delete[] mas;
    _getch();
}


void add_mas_values(int *A, int n) {
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)  {
        A[i] = rand() % 20;
    }
}


int mod_sum(int *A, int n) {
    int sum = 0;
    int ch = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)  {
        if (A[i] == 0) {
            ch = i;
        }
        else  {
            continue;
        }
    }

    for (; ch < n; ++ch)  {
        sum += abs(A[ch]);
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Я использовал функцию `rand() % 20` , то есть, как я понял, случайные числа должны быть от 0 до 20.

Но мне выдает огрооомное число типа: `33686151`

Почему? Я же правильно везде передал свой массив в функции.

Comment: А почему Вы решили, что среди этих чисел будет хоть один нуль?

Если его нет, то Вы просуммируете n + 1 элемент, начиная с A[-1] (а там скорее всего какое-то большое число (например, адрес от структур аллокатора памяти)).

Напишите  mod_sum() как-нибудь покороче, например:

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
      if (A[i] == 0) 
        for (++i; i < n; i++)
          sum += abs(A[j]);
    
    return sum;

обратите внимание, что во внутреннем цикле (в операторе `if`) можно менять переменную внешнего цикла так, что после его окончания автоматически завершается внешний цикл.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, действительно, ведь если у меня нет ни одного эл-та массива, равного нулю, то след проход по циклу у меня начинается с "-1" элемента!
Исправил на ваше решение, все работает!